# Not able to store large String in Clob

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Not able to store large size `String` in `CLOB`
`String` which contains xml data . the size of `String` is greater than 19000.
I am able to store small string but getting `null` value in database for large string.
Please suggest the solution for the same.
I am using following code:

```
Clob myClob = Hibernate.createClob(updateStr);
Reader reader = myClob.getCharacterStream();
myServiceRequest.setRequestData(Hibernate.createClob(reader, (int)myClob.length()));
```

`updateStr` is a String which contains xml data and its size is very large. that i am not able to insert in DB.

RequestData is column(type CLOB) in database where i am inserting String .

Comment: you have to post the code you are using to save

Comment: Does it work to Split the `updateStr` into Chunks and Enter These? Does `updateStr` contain Charakters Not Supportes by the Clob/Database Charset ? Have you tried to insert into a blob?